# Sending Serialized Data

Tags: java, udp, client-server

Basically I am doing some networking with a client and server sending "packets" back and forth to each other. I have it working with basic variable data such as ints or strings passing back and forth, however now I want to pass an object.

So I know I have to serialize the data of the object to pass it through the socket. That is working as well (as I can get the correct information if I serialize then de-serialize right away) but the problem comes in when my server receives a packet.

My server interprets packet data based on the first 2 characters of the packet. So `01foobar` is a type of packet correlating to whatever "01" is assigned to and `02foobar` is a different packet as well. So I don't know the best way to do this with an object attached. What is mean is this...

The way I have tried to do it right now is, serialize my object and get it's string. Then append on 03 to the front. So basically I have a string that looks like `03[B@3e9513b7` (or whatever) then do getBytes() on that string which gives me another `byte[]` (so I can send it through the socket). Then when the server receives that information, I can append the 03 off and I'm left with just `[B@3e9513b7`. The problem is, `[B@3e9513b7` is now a string, and not a byte[] and in order to deserialize I need to send it the same `byte[]` as it gave me when it serialized that data. So that got me looking into a way to make `[B@3e9513b7` BE the `byte[]` (aka, so when I do `toString()` on that new `byte[]` it returns `[B@3e9513b7`) but was having issues assigning it like that because it would give me a new `byte[]` for `[B@3e9513b7` as a string. So obviously then, when I send it to be deserialized it has a `byte[]` that it doesn't know what to do with and throws an error.

So I have to imagine there's a better way to do this, and I'm just making things more complicated than they should be. Any recommendations? I can provide code snippets if needed.

Thanks guys!

Edit: I guess I should mention that I am using Java with using UDP sockets.

Comment: Have you tried flattening the object to a JSON String?
http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/06/16/jackson-examples-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Using the Object's `toString()` method isn't comprehensive enough to rebuild the element; in order to do this, you'd have to override the `toString()` function.

Comment: I thought that's basically what serializing the object did. Basically compressed it to a bit array so that when you de-serialize, it will know what it is. I am serializing it now for that reason, and then turning the serialized bit array into a string so I can append it with the "03" the server needs in front to determine what kind of packet it's recieving. I'm not calling toString() on the object itself, I'm calling it on the bit array that I get when I serialize it.

Comment: There are also many JSON Serialization Frameworks, GSON is a pretty good one, take a look

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Are you able to serialize/deserialize the object without transmission?

Comment: Also, if you're interested in creating your own packet format, rather than serializing the object then building the packet, it may be worth serializing a packet object which contains the data to be transmitted. I mentioned using JSON because you said you could successfully transfer `String` data. JSON converts your Java object into an equivalent XML data structure, which you could transmit as a `String`. Calling `toString()` is not serializing the object. 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: How do you mean "without transmission"? If I serialize an object, I can pass it through the server and then deserialize it later and it comes out the way I want it to. However, the issue comes when I try to add "03". My server needs to know what packet it's receiving and the way I do this is by defining the first 2 characters of data that it receives as a number. So, for example, 01 signifies login, 02 signifies disconnect, etc. So I need to send 03Object. When I serialize, that comes out as 03[B@3e9513b7 but passing through a socket requires a byte[]. So its really 03[B@3e9513b7.getBytes()

Comment: The problem with that is when I receive it on the server side it sees "03[B@3e9513b7". So I can append off the 03 and be left with "[B@3e9513b7" but since my deserialize method is defined as deserialize(byte[] b) I can't pass it a string. And I have no way to tell it that [B@3e9513b7 is actually the byte array because (since it's a string) there's no way (that I know of) to do byte[] b = [B@3e9513b7

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a reliable and efficient solution for client-server communication, I would suggest to look at [Netty](http://netty.io/).

Regarding how to serialize/deserialize your objects, you have many choices as Java serialization, XML, JSON ...

You would have to pass your serialized objects in UDP datagrams. However, be aware that UDP datagram size is limited. If you're exchanging big objects, you may want to switch to TCP transport which is more reliable.

You may also want to look at SOAP/REST [web services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service).

Comment: So passing data isn't my issue here. I can pass data between the client and server just fine. My problem is that I have a byte array representing a serialized object and a string representing how the server should handle the packet. They need to be sent to the server as ONE packet. So to combine them, I call the toString() on my byte array, append 03 to the front of that string, then call getBytes() which turns that whole string back into a byte array so it can be sent through the socket. However, when the server receives them I can parse off the 03 but cant get the rest back to its byte array

Comment: toString will only show you the object type with id as defined in the Object super class, not the actual bytes

Comment: I guess I'm not being very clear. Sorry! What I mean to say is, I'm calling toString on my serialized byte array. So I call --> serialize(object) which returns a byte[]. So say, byte[] array = serialize(object); Then I'm doing array.toString() which returns something like [B@3e9513b7. So after the server receives the packet, my method is defined as deserialize(byte[] b). So I cant do deserialize("[B@3e9513b7") because that's a string. And I cant do byte[] b = [B@3e9513b7; deserialize(b) because, again, [B@3e9513b7 is a string. Is that more clear?

Comment: As I said, you error is that you think the string you get after calling toString is the actual bytes translated to String but it's not the case. Take a look at the Javadoc of the toString method defined in the Object class. What you can do is to decode your bytes array using some agreed charset (one that is agreed by both the client and the server) and pass the decoded string to the server. Then, on the server, you can encode the string using the same charset and you will get the original bytes array.